# How can I check if javascript array already contains a specific array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, include

I learn Javascript and read and understand how the `includes` works to test if a value exists in an array.

My problem comes when I have an Array of items that look like this this:

`state = { focused: null, files: [] };`:

The image show this here:
[image]

When I add a new `newFile` and it's the same it should not add it ok but the evaluation,

`if (newFile && !files.includes(newFile)) {..` always say false so how to test for this do I have to test on individual values inside `newFiles`?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.includes` will not do a deep comparison between object, only a shallow one comparing references. This way even objects that have same values they would fail on test because they have different references.

In your case you could compare `id`, which should be unique for each object. You can use `Array.every` that checks if all values pass in the test. This way you want to check that every file id doesn't match newFile id:

```
if (newFile && files.every(({id}) => newFile.id !== id))
```

Comment: yea your right thanks I'm loading files from Google Drive or local Filesystem and user can add file so must find a unique id. The filename is not enough and creating a file hash sum would be best, is that possible to do btw in React , in the doom

Comment: to create a hash in React you mean? I would say it's up to your needs to choose a suitable library to install in your project to generate the hash. React is a flexible library, it doesn't enforce you use one over the other. in the end, it's about to search some github repos and see "yeah, that works nice for my needs"

Comment: Hmm when I add the `if (newFile && files.every(({id}) => newFile.id !== id))` then when I debug I cant see what `id` is. It's like it's nothing. The `list` Array contains objects of the type `newFile` So I tried `if (newFile && files.every(({id}) => newFile.id !== id.id ))` but that dont work also. Maybe must create a new SO question I think for this

Comment: `files.every((file) => newFile.id !== file.id ))` . I extracted id from file with `{id}`. if you want to have access to file then don't extract id like I did

Comment: Strange I even change to test file size like `if (files.every((file) => newFile.size !== file.size )){` it just give true even the file is the same..hmm must create a Codesandbox 
`

Answer (score 0):

Array.includes does reference comparison for Array or Object, so instead you can use Array.filter

```
if (newFile && newFile.filter(e => { /*Comparison logic */ }).length > 0)
```